# Center text in div with image on left

Tags: html, css

Looking to have an image (logo) on the left side of a div with text (a title) centered on the div. A basic question, but some caveats.

If I use `position: absolute` on the image, the text is centered, but when I resize the window the image covers the text. Want this to be a responsive page where the text is centered until it hits the image and the won't overlap. https://jsfiddle.net/mwqwmkdm/

If I use `float: left` on the image, then the text is not really perfectly centered. https://jsfiddle.net/mwqwmkdm/1/

I could create a `margin-right` of equal size on the other side of the text, but then I'm wasting those pixels on smaller displays and I don't want to do that. Eventually, it will be more than that one line I am centering. https://jsfiddle.net/mwqwmkdm/2/

Basically, I want:

- the text centered as long as the screen is wide enough
- the text to wrap around the image and not be in front of or behind it when the screen isn't wide enough
- not to lose any screen space except for the image itself

Thanks

Comment: Also, there are many side divs... that come and go based on screen size. Not looking for a complicated media query solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to try an alternative to CSS float and positioning properties you can easily accomplish your task with [**CSS Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). Code is clean, simple, efficient and easy to maintain. Also, flexbox is now [supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/mwqwmkdm/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" heigth="100">
    <p>centered text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: aqua;
}

img {
    margin: 10px;
}

p {
    border: 1px dashed red;
    padding: 5px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here's one way to keep your text centered on the full width of the container, while not allowing the text and image to overlap on smaller screens. No flexbox, no deprecated tags. Just a very simple media query.

*Wide screen*

[image]

*Narrow Screen*

[image]

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/mwqwmkdm/6/)

Comment: Sorry, again the text is centered in the area left over by the image, not on the entire containing div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox like this:

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
}
.content{
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" heigth="100">
    <div class="content">
        Centered Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this out for more info https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background

**Edit:**

To center it  respect to the container you can use a modification of you second example using `float: left` but instead to set the margin to the `center` you would put the text in a `span` and set the margin-right to it like this:

```css
img {
    float: left;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;    
}
.content span{
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" heigth="100">
    <div class="content">
        <span>Centered Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks to suffer the same problem as my second solution above. The text is centered in the area left over after the logo is placed. It is not centered on the div that contains both the image and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Flex box has compability problems with some browser. Just Create BFC for the `<center></center>` using `overflow:hidden;`
Check this out! [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o91rhuas/1/)

Comment: Please advise which browser flexbox has compatibility problems with. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: IE 8 and 9 and 10 and android 4.3 and 4.1

Comment: My mistake. I tend to ignore those browsers. I sometimes forget that other people still have to consider them. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated, so I really think that answers that steer OP away from using it are preferred.

Comment: @Michael_B I think that most positioning issues can be resolved by those "old-fashioned" ways. Thus, I would not chose new techs that's new and may have some compatibility problems. Unless they are the only solutions.

Comment: I don't disagree. But like @MaximillianLaumeister has noted, using a deprecated tag like `<center>` isn't the best way to go. It's [in the process of being dropped by the browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: Yes, sure. Thats my fault. But i just copied what @Mike used. ;-( I should have corrected that.

Comment: Sorry, but again text isn't centered in the DIV. It is centered in the area left over after the image is shown. Also, I used the `center` tag as a way of indicating which text was centered. I'm really trying to center a `h2` which is directly under a Google Banner Ad that is of similar width and is properly centered, which makes the header being shifted 50 pixels right look dumb.

Comment: Right. Understood. I think I covered your requirement in my revised answer. If I missed something please advise.